# Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set VBA

Tags: vba, runtime

I am getting the `Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set` in this part:

```
  Dim cn As ADODB.Connection: Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

    schema_nm = dbsheet.cb_BU.Value

    If conn_to_SQL(cn) = False Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Call any_action(cn, "Load Part")
    If Not user_active = 1 Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    SkipSave = True


    If MDIsheet.AutoFilter.FilterMode = True Then MDIsheet.ShowAllData <----HERE
```

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It tells you that `MDIsheet` hasn't been assigned to an object. Specifically, a worksheet.